# How to find the element in the json with using stream()?

Tags: java, json, stream, java-stream

I was working on my project, then I need the reach an element in the Json Data Look like:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Julide",
    "school": [
      {
        "surname": "Batur",
        "major": 
          {
            "date": 1615370705561,
            "teacher": "Mehmet"
          }
        ]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

So I can reach the element of name with:

```
var myData = data().
                stream().
                filter(x -> x.getFirstname().equals("Julide"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .get(0);
```

So, how to reach the **teacher** with using stream() in java 8?

Also, the getFirstname() where I called;

```
@Getter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "firstname",
        "school",
})
public class Package {
@JsonProperty("firstname")
    private String firstname;
@JsonProperty("school")
    private List<School> school;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Each `Package` has mutliple `School`s. Which `School` should be returned? --- A remark: `...collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0)` can be simplified to `...findFirst()`.

Comment: No, not really. There are still multiple `School`s per `Package`. Which school should be returned and by what criteria?

Comment: Name of package is not important actually, it can be x or z, I just call the getFirstname() from there. That's why I gave the example of my class. @Turing85

Comment: Can you look again to the question please? @Turing85

Comment: It is not about the name of `Package` (which I imagine should be a `Person` or `Trainee` or something like this). In the post, you asked how to return **one `School`**, but for each `Package` there can be **multiple `School`s** (it is a list after all). Which `School` should be returned?

Comment: yes I fixed that part, I want to know how to reach to the teacher. @Turing85

Comment: hmm... give me a second... that is a nasty one...

Comment: oke of course.....

Comment: By the way I don't have to reach to the "Julide", I just gave example.

Comment: Assuming standard getters, this should work: `...stream().filter(x -> x.getSchools().stream().map(School::getMajor).map(Major::getTeacher).anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual("Mehmet"))).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming standard getters, the following should work:

```
data.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getSchools().stream()            // for each school...
                .map(School::getMajor)                  // ... map it to the major...
                .map(Major::getTeacher)                 // ... map the major to the teacher
                .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual("Mehmet"))) // return true, if any teacher is "Mehmet"
        .findFirst()      // return the first student satisfying this criteria...
        .orElse(null));   // ... or null if none match
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EBg7CP) (the POJOs were simplified to the necessary fields to solve the problem).

The code will return the first `Trainee` found that has a `School`, which has a `Course`, whose `teacher` is `"Mehmet"`, or `null` if no such `Trainee` is found.

Comment: I learnt how to do it with you. I applied on the other problems.